# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> Returns null list

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Hoping someone can catch what I'm doing wrong.  CardCollection.cs just contains a List called cards, with a public methods Cards to act as getter/setter.

I should point out that I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for development, and when I inspect the string "jsonString" in debug mode using the built-in JSON Visualizer it displays properly in that window.  Unfortunately JsonConvert.DeserializeObject does not properly set my CardCollection object and results in an empty list of cards

**From "Form.cs"**

```
private async void SelectFileButton_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "JSON Files|*.json";
        dialog.Title = "Select a JSON File";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string line = "";
            string jsonString = "";

            string fileName = dialog.FileName;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(dialog.FileName))
            {
                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    line = line.Replace("\t", "");
                    line = line.Replace("\n", "");
                    builder.Append(line);
                }
            }

            jsonString = builder.ToString();

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
            };

            CardCollection cardList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CardCollection>(jsonString, settings);
        }
    }
```

**Card.cs**

```
public class Card
{
    string[] colorIdentity;
    string[] colors;
    double convertedManaCost;
    ForeignData[] foreignData;
    bool isReserved;
    string layout;
    Legality[] legalities;
    string loyalty;
    string manaCost;
    string name;
    string power;
    string[] printings;
    Ruling[] rulings;
    string[] subtypes;
    string[] supertypes;
    string text;
    string toughness;
    string type;
    string[] types;
    string uuid;

    public string[] ColorIdentity { get => colorIdentity; set => colorIdentity = value; }
    public string[] Colors { get => colors; set => colors = value; }
    public double ConvertedManaCost { get => convertedManaCost; set => convertedManaCost = value; }
    public bool IsReserved { get => isReserved; set => isReserved = value; }
    public string Layout { get => layout; set => layout = value; }
    public string Loyalty { get => loyalty; set => loyalty = value; }
    public string ManaCost { get => manaCost; set => manaCost = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public string Power { get => power; set => power = value; }
    public string[] Printings { get => printings; set => printings = value; }
    public string[] Subtypes { get => subtypes; set => subtypes = value; }
    public string[] Supertypes { get => supertypes; set => supertypes = value; }
    public string Text { get => text; set => text = value; }
    public string Toughness { get => toughness; set => toughness = value; }
    public string Type { get => type; set => type = value; }
    public string[] Types { get => types; set => types = value; }
    public string Uuid { get => uuid; set => uuid = value; }
    internal ForeignData[] ForeignData { get => foreignData; set => foreignData = value; }
    internal Legality[] Legalities { get => legalities; set => legalities = value; }
    internal Ruling[] Rulings { get => rulings; set => rulings = value; }
}
```

#### Here is  sample of the JSON file

```
{
"1999 World Championships Ad": {
    "colorIdentity": [],
    "colors": [],
    "convertedManaCost": 0.0,
    "foreignData": [],
    "isReserved": false,
    "layout": "token",
    "legalities": {},
    "name": "1999 World Championships Ad",
    "printings": [
        "WC99"
    ],
    "rulings": [],
    "starter": true,
    "subtypes": [],
    "supertypes": [],
    "text": "",
    "type": "Card",
    "types": [
        "Card"
    ],
    "uuid": "8635dea0-985a-4c02-a02b-8b08d96fb2dd"
},
"2004 World Championships Ad": {
    "colorIdentity": [],
    "colors": [],
    "convertedManaCost": 0.0,
    "foreignData": [],
    "isReserved": false,
    "layout": "token",
    "legalities": {},
    "name": "2004 World Championships Ad",
    "printings": [
        "WC04"
    ],
    "rulings": [],
    "starter": true,
    "subtypes": [],
    "supertypes": [],
    "text": "",
    "type": "Card",
    "types": [
        "Card"
    ],
    "uuid": "cbd6a762-f3c2-4b29-a07e-f0c9c81cf1ec"
},
"A Display of My Dark Power": {
    "colorIdentity": [],
    "colors": [],
    "convertedManaCost": 0.0,
    "foreignData": [],
    "isReserved": false,
    "layout": "scheme",
    "legalities": {},
    "name": "A Display of My Dark Power",
    "printings": [
        "ARC"
    ],
    "rulings": [
        {
            "date": "2010-06-15",
            "text": "The ability affects all players, not just you."
        },
        {
            "date": "2010-06-15",
            "text": "The effect doesn’t wear off until just before your next untap step (even if an effect will cause that untap step to be skipped)."
        },
        {
            "date": "2010-06-15",
            "text": "The types of mana are white, blue, black, red, green, and colorless."
        },
        {
            "date": "2010-06-15",
            "text": "If a land produces more than one type of mana at a single time (as Boros Garrison does, for example), the land’s controller chooses which one of those types of mana is produced by the delayed triggered ability."
        },
        {
            "date": "2010-06-15",
            "text": "If a land is tapped for mana but doesn’t produce any (for example, if you tap Gaea’s Cradle for mana while you control no creatures), the delayed triggered ability won’t trigger."
        }
    ],
    "starter": true,
    "subtypes": [],
    "supertypes": [],
    "text": "When you set this scheme in motion, until your next turn, whenever a player taps a land for mana, that player adds one mana of any type that land produced.",
    "type": "Scheme",
    "types": [
        "Scheme"
    ],
    "uuid": "c5287e77-890d-41bd-acc6-7a8f1866426d"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried  dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and see if that works

Comment: As an aside, if you're using C# 3.0 or later. your `Card` could use auto properties to save on some boilerplate, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> "1999 World Championships Ad": {
> ```

What you have here is an object, not an array. You should deserialize it as a dictionary:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Card>>(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Card`does not match your json in several ways. There are several good ways to create classes for serializing/deserializing json directly.

Method 1:

- Copy your json example containing all possible keys.
- In Visual Studio 2017. Edit->Paste Special->Paste Json as classes

This will create the classes you need to deserialize your data.

Method 2:
Use [Quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io). Paste you json and get the classes needed in your favorite language.

One extra problem with you class `Card` is that the property names are case sensitive! ColorIdentity != colorIdentity.

If you want to keep PascalCasing in your code, but have camelCasing in your Json you need to decorate each property like this:

```
[JsonProperty("colorIdentity")]
public object[] ColorIdentity { get; set; }
```

Also the names of the competitions in your json are objects that are not present in your classes. If you follow method 1 or 2 you will see what I mean.